# Model selection in Gamma GLM with identity link

Tags: generalized-linear-model, model-selection, gamma-distribution

I have used Gamma distribution in my GLM with identity link. I want to do backward model selection with drop1 command in R as described in Zuur, 2009. But I get this warning message:

```
Error: no valid set of coefficients has been found:
  please supply starting values
        In addition: Warning message:
        In log(ifelse(y == 0, 1, y/mu)) : NaNs produced
```

When using log link it works fine. Why am I getting this message when using Identity link? What is the best option for my model selection?

Comment: Backward selection is not a good method, as has been discussed here a lot.

The rest of your question seems more appropriate to either StackOverflow, an R-list, or the developers of the package.

Comment: The problem with the identity link is that the linear predictor may produce negative values which do not make sense as the expected value of a gamma distribution. That is the probable reason for the message you have shown us!