# Tiny partial effects but high R² in GAMs - and the other way around

Tags: r, model-selection, generalized-additive-model, mgcv, partial-effect

I am currently running GAMs with `mgcv` package and am trying to find a good one by looking at `summary()` and the visual outputs from `gratia::appraise()` and `gratia::draw()`.
When I started, I built simple models chosing the most important variables according to my hypotheses and previous data exploration but never yielded model outputs that were looking reasonable to me. Specifically, i) the model metrics like R² or explained deviance were very low, ii) the diagnostic plots like QQ, residual plot and observed vs. fitted were looking bad, and/or iii) the plotted smoothers from `gratia::draw()` were looking like nonsense (i.e. the partial effects were tiny, the residuals plotted on top of the estimated smooth functions were spread way beyond the smoothers' confidence ribbons, and the results are BS as the tiny partial effects that are there often point in the wrong direction etc).
Obviously, I thought I was doing it wrong and have since been digging myself deeper into all kinds of extensions and alternatives to the simple models I started with:

- transforming predictor variables
- adding interactions between predictors in all ways possible
- adding more explanatory variables, as smoothers and as parametric components
- testing all kinds of basis functions with the `bs=` argument
- introducing a grouping factor (2 levels) with `by=` argument and with `bs="fs"` to all major predictors
- changing basis size via `k=` for all predictors
- setting extra penalties with e.g. `select=T`
- trying a forward selection by adding predictors one-by-one and comparing models
- using different families that can be applied to my continuous, positive response variable
- trying all kinds of possible links that go with those families

All of that seemed futile. The first time I ever saw something that 'made sense' was when I had tried a model with a Gamma family and an identity link, which gives a warning and [thanks to the community, I now know is sub-optimal](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/624061). For example, see `gratia::draw()` output of a Gamma model using 3 different link functions, formula `mgcv::gam(y ~ s(var1) + s(var2) + s(var3) + s(var4) +grouping_factor, family=Gamma(link="xyz"),method="REML",data = data)` (whereby they only differ wrt the link specified instead of "xyz"):
[image: gratia::draw() output of a Gamma model using 3 different link functions, formula mgcv::gam(y ~ s(var1) + s(var2) + s(var3) + s(var4) +grouping_factor, family=Gamma(link="xyz"),method="REML",data = data) (whereby they only differ wrt the link specified instead of "xyz")]

As you can see, the canonical inverse link function (and to some extend also the log link) only creates tiny partial effects for each predictor, causing the estimated smoother to be reduced to a thin line drawn through a seemingly unrelated point cloud of residuals; I have also found that generally all inverse-link models have all predictors point to the wrong direction. Not plotting the residuals makes curvature of estimated smoothers visible, but they often point in the wrong direction, or are flat alltogether, and anyways tiny. So when I started seeing outputs like the bottom left panels and the smoothers finally made sense to me I was very excited, until I was told I shouldn't use the identity link in Gamma family models.
Consequently, I checked all other model versions again, changing family and/or link function, looking very closely at diagnostic plots again and searching for the models with highest explanatory power. And here is the conundrum: There ain't one single combination, in which all 3 aspects come together! I either have models with explained Deviance >70% and adj. R²>0.6, but their estimated smoothers are BS, the partial effects being tiny:
**Model 1**
[image]

```
Family: gaussian Link function: log 
Formula: y ~ group + s(var7) + s(var8) + s(var9) + s(var10) + s(var4)
Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.3926     0.1211  11.499  < 2e-16 ***
groupgroup2   0.5797     0.1318   4.398 3.85e-05 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Approximate significance of smooth terms:
           edf Ref.df      F p-value    
s(var7)  1.001  1.002  1.473  0.2291    
s(var8)  3.135  3.857  3.531  0.0113 *  
s(var9)  3.127  3.917  1.868  0.1245    
s(var10) 3.035  3.651  2.804  0.0342 *  
s(var4)  2.189  2.583 25.647  <2e-16 ***
---
R-sq.(adj) =  0.657   Deviance explained = 71.2%
-REML = 231.03  Scale est. = 9.3443    n = 80
```

Or I got estimated smoother functions that are acceptable with residuals plotted somewhat following the smoother, but there explained deviance and adj. R² are much much lower:
**Model 2:**
[image]

```
Family: Gamma Link function: log 
Formula: y ~ group + s(var7) + s(var8) + s(var9) + s(var10) + s(var4)
Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   1.2641     0.1088  11.621  < 2e-16 ***
groupgroup2   0.6171     0.1657   3.724 0.000398 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Approximate significance of smooth terms:
           edf Ref.df      F  p-value    
s(var7)  1.280  1.495  0.081 0.832939    
s(var8)  4.220  5.178  4.624 0.000899 ***
s(var9)  4.009  4.949  3.825 0.004585 ** 
s(var10) 3.097  3.797  7.626  8.8e-05 ***
s(var4)  1.000  1.001 16.146 0.000149 ***
---
R-sq.(adj) =  0.528   Deviance explained = 59.4%
-REML = 223.37  Scale est. = 0.41755   n = 80
```

And here for comparison one of the Gamma models with identity link, that appear so much better but give the warning:
**Model 3**
[image]

```
Family: Gamma Link function: identity 
Formula: y ~ group + s(var1) + s(var2) + s(var3) + s(var4) + s(var5) + 
    s(var6) + ti(var1, var6)
Parametric coefficients:
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   5.2896     0.4292  12.326  < 2e-16 ***
groupgroup2   2.3441     0.6515   3.598 0.000588 ***
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
Approximate significance of smooth terms:
                edf Ref.df      F  p-value    
s(var1)       1.110  1.205  0.046 0.885700    
s(var2)       1.000  1.000 13.100 0.000549 ***
s(var3)       3.517  4.193 11.762 5.36e-07 ***
s(var4)       1.333  1.568  6.631 0.007083 ** 
s(var5)       1.130  1.243 12.183 0.002437 ** 
s(var6)       1.154  1.283  0.154 0.694622    
ti(var1,var6) 1.408  1.711 15.053 2.04e-05 ***
---
R-sq.(adj) =  0.504   Deviance explained = 65.1%
-REML = 209.11  Scale est. = 0.33714   n = 80
```

**My Questions:**

1. How come I don't seem to see a good fit in `gratia::draw()´ even though the goodness-of-fit metrics suggest there is a fit? Then how can the partial effects be so small at the same time?
2. How can the goodness-of-fit metrics get so much worse in the second model (with the same predictors like in the first) although the graphic representation of the estimated smoothers seem so much better?
3. And is there no way I can use the 3rd model, despite the combination of Gamma family with an identity link being sub-optimal?
   Maybe there is stuff that I don't see and understand or something in the plots catches your eyes then please let me know, because quite frankly, I am lost here.

Sorry for the lengthy post, Grateful for your insights and Thank you all.